# Send data from web Application to ESP32 or ESp8266

Tags: web-applications, automation, esp32, arduino-esp8266, home-automation

I am working on Home Automation project. I am stuck on getting data from web application to my ESP.I had successfully send data from ESP to web API. We are in progress of developing web application. The problem I am facing is how do I receive command from that web app on my esp.  If anyone have any idea then please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

look this example, is a simple webserver with Esp32. In this example you can turn LEDs from the web page.

[Esp32 web Server](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/)